# Prevent input on table cell after fixed width reached?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, cell

I would like to prevent additional input on a HTML table cell once it's width is reached.

The table has a fixed layout, no wrap and a specific width. The overflow is currently set to hidden.

Is it possible to filter (and ultimately prevent) input so that it stops at the fixed width so that there will be no overflow (hidden or otherwise). I am currently filtering carriage return using jQuery so that the cell will not expand to additional lines.

Perhaps I am asking too much from a HTML table...

Comment: How do you want to measure width? The CSS width of the cell or the number of characters it contains?

Comment: You bring up an interesting question, but I had originally thought to measure using width. Number of characters should be easy to figure using Samuel's answer below and just checking for length of the input string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to copy the cell content on `keydown` in an hidden field and to compute the value of this field:

```
$("table input").on("keydown", function(e) {
    $("#copy").text(this.value);

    var width = $("#copy").outerWidth();
    console.log("w: " + width);

    var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if (width > 50 && code  !== 8 && code !== 49) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

I have created a fiddle with such solution : http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/hnRjB/2/.

A point to be noted is that the font-family and font-size should be the same in the `input` and in the `div` in order to have the correct value, that is the reason of the CSS rule :

```
* {
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 1em;  
}
```

But instead of `*`, you should restrict to suits your needs (for example, `table input, #copy`).

---

**EDIT :**

Just note that with this code, the user can enter just more than the input length, but you can add some "long" character to your copied field, in order to test the width : http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/hnRjB/3/.

Comment: This seems to be the answer I was going after. It may be a bit more complicated as there may be graphics in the table cell as well. I will just have to accommodate for the width of the graphics.